# PHP - output values of a variable

Tags: php, wordpress

I am a newbie to php. I am working on a existing wordpress site.  I want to print the values of a variable  $post  as output. What is the  equivalent of Java's System.out.print in php.

While googling i found the same, system.out.print for php but its not working.

--
Thanks

Comment: I think you're looking for `echo $post`...

Comment: Hint: you want to **print** something...

Answer (score 5):

You can use `echo` to print something: [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php)

`$_POST` is an array, if you want to examine its value for debug purposes use `var_dump` [(docs)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php):

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

To access array's elements, use square brackets: `$_POST['index']`. PHP arrays may be associative, which means they are indexed not only by numbers, but also by strings. `$_POST` is a pure associative array, indexed only with strings.

To print POST parameter called `username` use this code:

```
echo $_POST['username'];
```

or

```
echo($_POST['username']);
```

Both will work because echo is not a function, but a language construct (see docs linked above).

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("var = %s", $var);
```

or

```
echo $var;
```

or (for objects, arrays, etc)

```
print_r($_POST);
```

or

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

Check php.net for more!

Answer (score 0):

PHP's [echo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) construct is probably what you want.

```
<?php echo $_POST['variable']; ?>
```

where `variable` is the name of the form element.